# Can there be a perfect square whose digits consist of exactly 4 ones, 4 twos and 4 zeros in any order?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any perfect square whose digits consist of exactly 4 ones, 4 twos and 4 zeros in any order?

Comment: If I counted correctly there are just 23100 such numbers, assuming leading $0$s aren't allowed.  A computer could check them all quickly.  There are much easier "by hand" methods.

Answer (score 10):

No because the number will be divisible by $3$ but not by $9$.

Comment: WOW. I just wrote a little program to generate every combination of those digits, and calculate their square root. Such a waste of time, your way of solving it was much much better :D.